# Variables anónimas

Tags: c++

```
typedef void (*tipo)(int a, int b);

tipo( []( int as, int bes ) {} );
tipo( nullptr );
```

Entiendo lo que significa la primera línea pero las dos ultimas no consigo saber como interpretarlas.Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: donde dije que fuera invalida @Trauma ;)... pero no leyo ni el recorrido OP ;)

Comment: ustedes son los expertos en C(++).. yo no me meto aca...

Answer (score 2):

Las 2 últimas líneas son, ambas, **creación de variables anónimas**; es decir, se crea una variable **sin nombre**, cuyo tiempo de vida se limita a la sentencia en la que se declara. Y tiene **muy poca utilidad en C**:

```
typedef void ( *tipo )( int a, int b );

int main( void ) {
  tipo;

  return 0;
}
```

> warning: useless type name in empty declaration

Fíjate que es un *aviso*, no un error. El compilador nos deja, pero ya nos está avisando de que eso no sirve para nada: `nombre de tipo sin uso en declaración vacía`.

En C++, **si puede** ser de alguna utilidad, si la variable es una instancia de clase: en ese caso, se invocaría tanto **al constructor** como **al destructor**, con los posibles *efectos colaterales* que esto pueda tener.

```
#include <iostream>

struct tipo {
  ~tipo( ) { std::cout << "destructor\n"; }
  tipo( ) { std::cout << "constructor\n"; }
  tipo( int x ) { std::cout << "constructor con " << x << '\n'; }
};

int main( ) {
  tipo( );
  tipo( 10 );

  return 0;
}
```

> constructor
>   destructor
>   constructor con 10
>   destructor

Fíjate en el orden de los mensajes: primero, se crea y se destruye una instancia de `tipo`, usando su constructor por defecto `tipo( )`. **Después** se crea y se destruye otra instancia de `tipo` usando el constructor con 1 argumento `tipo( int x )`.

El el código de ejemplo, puesto que `tipo` es un *alias* para un puntero, es prácticamente equivalente al lenguaje C: el tipo `tipo` **no tiene** constructor ni destructor, por lo que no hay posibles efectos colaterales, y ambas sentencias son equivalentes: **no hacen nada**:

```
typedef void ( *tipo )( int a, int b );

tipo( []( int as, int bes ) { } );
tipo( nullptr );
```

> warning: statement has no effect `tipo( nullptr );`.

¿Porqué no nos avisa en la primera declaración `tipo( []( int as, int bes ) { } );`? Bueno, básicamente, porque el compilador **tiene en límite** en cuan *inteligente* es; ahí, estamos creando tanto una variable anónima como una [*expresión lambda*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_lambda#C++_(desde_C++11)) ... y parece que esto es suficiente para *confundir* al compilador y no emitir ningún aviso.

Fíjate que, en realidad, el código es exactamente igual de *inútil*: definimos una variable que inicializamos con la dirección de una función ... a la que nunca podremos llamar, puesto que la variable deja de existir al final de su propia declaración.

Comment: Las expresiones lambda suelen compilarse como objetos que sobrecargan el operador función. Un objeto puede tener, como has comentado, implicaciones en el constructor y/o el destructor, lo cual sería motivo suficiente para desactivar el warning

Comment: Muy buena observación. Lo añado.

Comment: No se, es una posible explicación. A ver si se pasa por aquí @PaperBirdMaster y nos resuelve la duda... a mi es que me da muuuuuucha pereza ponerme a mirar el estándar :S

Comment: Se lo estoy consultando en el *chat*, a ver que opina O_O

Comment: El estándar no dirá nunca dónde poner o no poner alarmas; éstas son dependientes de implementación. Lo más cercano que tiene el estándar a "alarmas" es la frase "*No diagnostic required*" que viene a decir, a grandes rasgos: "Esto podría no estar bien, pero lo más seguro es que sea inocuo".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster eso lo se, la duda venía a si la explicación que dado sobre por qué no salen warnings en el caso de la lambda te parece razonable a ti también o no :)

Comment: @eferion no es que me parezca razonable esa explicación. Es que **ES** esa explicación. He dado [un monólogo en el chat al respecto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49412121#49412121).

Answer (score 2):

Cuando no entiendo una pieza de código, intento verbalizarla. Hagamos ese ejercicio.

> ```
> typedef void (*tipo)(int a, int b);
> ```

Define (`def`) un tipo (`type`) que será un puntero (`*`) a una función que no devuelve nada (`void`) y recibe dos parámetros de tipo entero (`int`), llamaremos `tipo` a este tipo.

> ```
> tipo( []( int as, int bes ) {} );
> ```

Construye una instancia de `tipo` pasando como parámetro de construcción una lambda que no captura nada (`[]`), que recibe dos enteros (`int`) como parámetro y que no hace nada (`{}`).

> ```
> tipo( nullptr );
> ```

Construye una instancia de `tipo` pasando como parámetro de construcción un puntero (`ptr`) nulo (`null`).

Ahora todo junto:

```
typedef void (*tipo)(int a, int b);

tipo( []( int as, int bes ) {} );
tipo( nullptr );
```

Define un tipo que será un puntero a una función que no devuelve nada y recibe dos parámetros de tipo entero, llamaremos `tipo` a este tipo. A continuación construye una instancia de `tipo` pasando como parámetro de construcción una lambda que no captura nada, que recibe dos enteros como parámetro y que no hace nada y para acabar construye una instancia de `tipo` pasando como parámetro de construcción un puntero nulo.